# Multiple View for 1 BloC or 1 Bloc per View

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

and learning bloc patern

[image: Multiple View for 1 bloc]

[image: 1 Bloc for 1 View]

Which one is right ?

Comment: It really depends on your specific use case, but maybe this can help you learn more about Bloc https://medium.com/codechai/effective-bloc-pattern-45c36d76d5fe

Answer (score 1):

First screen can be applicable when in several ui s the business logic are the same.

Second one can be applicable when the business logic are different.

So first understand case.

Answer (score 0):

Update 
Bloc Documentation itself not recommended using multiple bloc for one view, because it will make bloc to bloc communication.

> Because blocs expose streams, it may be tempting to make a bloc which listens to another bloc. You should not do this. There are better alternatives than resorting to the code below:

[image]

source : [bloc to bloc communication](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture?id=bloc-to-bloc-communication)